# cannot reindex pandas dataframe with required indexes

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data frame `df` in `pandas` like this:

```
                                         signal1
timestamp                                       
2017-08-23 21:30:00.012                 181643.0
2017-08-23 21:31:00.002                 181635.0
2017-08-23 21:32:00.003                 181630.0
2017-08-23 21:33:00.006                 181611.0
2017-08-23 21:34:00.002                 181644.0
```

and I have indexes as this:

```
[2017-08-23 14:30:00-07:00, 2017-08-23 14:31:00-07:00, 2017-08-23 14:32:00-07:00, 2017-08-23 14:33:00-07:00, 2017-08-23 14:34:00-07:00, 2017-08-23 14:35:00-07:00]
```

Now if I re-index `df` like this:

```
df = df.reindex(indexes)
```

the output is:

```
timestamp                                    signal1
2017-08-23 14:30:00-07:00                      NaN
2017-08-23 14:31:00-07:00                      NaN
2017-08-23 14:32:00-07:00                      NaN
2017-08-23 14:33:00-07:00                      NaN
2017-08-23 14:34:00-07:00                      NaN
2017-08-23 14:35:00-07:00                      NaN
```

I want the output to be:

```
signal_name                                    signal1
2017-08-23 14:30:00-07:00                      181643.0
2017-08-23 14:31:00-07:00                      181643.0
2017-08-23 14:32:00-07:00                      181643.0
2017-08-23 14:33:00-07:00                      181643.0
2017-08-23 14:34:00-07:00                      181643.0
2017-08-23 14:35:00-07:00                        NaN
```

I am not getting why it is not re-indexing correctly.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html): "Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index.". There are no values for `signal1` at the given timestamps.

Comment: It seems like all you want to do is reset the index. Not reindex.

Comment: And `reset_index()` wouldn't do what you want.The index object is immutable.

Comment: If you see carefully, the indexes that are needed are offset by 7 hours. Hence, they have the same index as the originals. The only difference is one have accuracy of ms and other is in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas-series-reindex) do is

> Conform Series to new index with optional filling logic, placing
>   NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index.

mean you don't have `2017-08-23 14:30:00-07:00` in previous index,so it's NaN.
It you have `2017-08-23 21:30:00.012` or other origin index,it would change the maping of your data and index.

[Index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html#pandas.Index) is immutable object.

> Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set. The basic
>   object storing axis labels for all pandas objects

so you need create a new instance with your new index and origin data.

`Series(data=origin_data, index=new_index)`

or

`Dataframe(data=origin_data, index=new_index)`